# How to get CSS button added to Django admin to actually trigger logic

Tags: django, django-views, export, django-queryset

The 'Export' button I've added to my Django admin won't hook to my view even though the button itself shows up on screen. I've used several tutorials on SO to get the button visible - BUT it just does nothing when clicked, reloads the same page. I have a feeling that the structure of how I have it set up is wrong or that I'm not passing it the data from my database correctly.

- I'm assuming there are errors here that I am missing?
- How do I pass my export function the data that is already in my
  database? I figure I have to do a queryset but I'm not sure I'm
  actually getting the data or putting it in the right place. The
  button is intended to let the user export all data that has already
  been stored (e.g. all records of a particular type) to an Excel file.

My app > css > categories.css (to create the button)

```
.btn{
    border: solid 1px #000;
    background: #eee;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Changes I made to the `change_list.html` template to get my button to be visible (I put it after the search bar on admin change list):

```
{% block search %}{% search_form cl %} <form action="#" method="get">
 <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Export" name="export" align="right">{% endblock %}
```

views.py:

```
from django.template import RequestContext

def excel_view(request):
    attorney_range = Attorney.objects.all().filter(active=True)
    if request.GET.get('export'):
        if 'export' in request.GET:
            response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/vnd.ms-excel')
            response[
                'Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=Report.xlsx'
            xlsx_data = WriteToExcel(attorney_range)
            response.write(xlsx_data)
            return response
        else:
            return render("change_list.html",
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request),
                          template_name='change_list.html')
```

A file called excel_utils.py where my export-to-Excel function lives:

```
from io import StringIO
import xlsxwriter
from django.utils.translation import ugettext
from .models import Attorney


def WriteToExcel(attorney_range):
    attorney_range = Attorney.objects.all().filter(active=True)
    output = StringIO.StringIO()
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(output)
    worksheet_s = workbook.add_worksheet("Summary")

    # excel styles here

    attorney_range = Attorney.objects.all()
    attorney_list = []
    for x in attorney_range:
        attorney_list.append(x)
    for idx, data in enumerate(attorney_list):
        row = 5 + idx
        worksheet_s.write_boolean(row, 1, cell_center)
        worksheet_s.write_string(row, 2, attorney_list.index(2))
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Wiring up the button

It's not evident how your custom view is being invoked. The view that is called to render an admin page is built-in to the `django_admin` package. When you use `<form action="#" method="get">` in an admin template, you're asking for the request to be processed by the original admin view. Since your code is in a custom view, this is probabaly not what you want. You've got options:

0) Move your code into the admin view processor. Not happening.

1) Keep the form button and set `action="/your/custom/view"` to call your custom view. If you do this you'll still need to check the request object for the GET parameters (`if request.GET.get('export')`) and branch accordingly, or,

2) Forgo the form button and just place a standard `<a href>` link to call the view that generates your Excel file, avoiding the use of the HTML form element. The results is a standard URL like `http://hostname.com/attorney/summary/xlsx` that can be linked from anywhere.

#### Passing the data

I'll assume you're using the approach covered in your [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39726884/split-csv-file-using-python-shows-not-all-data-in-excel). Without scrutinizing the details in the sample code here, your approach is generally correct. A couple of tips:

Generate the queryset only after you've determined you need it. Instead of:

```
attorney_range = Attorney.objects.all().filter(active=True)
if request.GET.get('export'):
    ...
```

do

```
if request.GET.get('export'):
    attorney_range = Attorney.objects.all().filter(active=True)
    ...
```

You have the right intention in creating it in the view and passing it into the helper function. No need to recreate it twice in the helper function.

Genericize the `WriteToExcel()` function if you can, so that it doesn't care what model is being passed in or what field types are being exported.